# Machine learning: PCA for different number of features

Tags: machine-learning, pca, supervised-learning, mfcc

I am quite new in machine learning and I am building a simple app to recognize spoken digits.
I used [MFCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) to extract the filtering characteristic of my audio files. MFCC outputs me a 13 x length_of_audio matrix. I would like to use this information for my feature vector. But obviously, each example would have different number of features.
My question is what are the approaches to handle different number of features. E.g. could I use PCA to always extract some fixed amount of features and then use them in a particular learning algorithm ?
I would like to use logistic regression as the learning algorithm.

This is what I received at analyzing one of the spoken digits.
[image: MFCC]

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you have for a user a length_of_audio_matrix = N you don't have a feature vector of 13*N, you have N features vectors of length 13 (they compose a sequence but they are different feature vectors).

You must compose a matrix of 13 features:

```
MFCCUser1,Slot1
MFCCUser1,Slot2
....
MFCCUser1,SlotN
MFCCUser2,Slot1
MFCCUser2,Slot2
...
```

And then you can apply Principal Component Analysis.

You only have 13 features, do you really need to reduce them?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't really understand what do you mean: "You only have 13 features" ? See the figure I added to my question, I think all the small squares in the MFCC "heatmap" are features, which gives me in this case a feature vector of length around 13*85

Comment: If I understand your problem, you have audio records. To extract the features you divide the signal into pieces of X miliseconds and after that you extract 13MFCC components on every audio piece. If you want to use PCA you must use PCA on the 13 lenght MFCC components vectors (all of them have the same length). But PCA is used to reduce the number of features, you are handling only 13 I don't see the need to reduce them.

Comment: Yes, I have audio records. Each audio record has at most 1 second. I divided 1 second of an audio record into 100 audio pieces, each 10ms. MFCC outputs 13 features per an 10ms audio piece, because I have at most 100 pieces (some audios have less than 1 second) -> I have 13 features * 100 pieces = 1300 features for 1 second audio record. And my question is: because not all audio records have exactly 1 second, therefore I won't always get a 1300 feature vector, so may I use PCA to reduce the number of feature to a specific number, s.t. I can apply ML algo?
Or is there another better approach ?

Comment: No, you cannot use PCA. From the point of view of ML, you have transformed your audio record in a concatenation of 100 pieces of 13 features, not a piece of 1300 features, So you can use PCA on the individual 13 features vectors, but your problem will be the same, your audio records will be different. You can use a different approach to use ML, if you can use different techniques (You can use GMMs to create a model of every audio record because now it is composed by a Group of subsamples) or you can classify audio records with algorithms that work with sequences (for example HMMs or RNNs)